# My FloatingActionButton has some weird lines coming out of it on 4.4 and lower

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-design-library, floating-action-button

As the title says, my `FloatingActionButton` has some weird lines coming out of it only on 4.4 or lower. On Lollipop it works fine.

This is a picture of the issue:

[image: FAB]

The play image doesn't have those lines in it. My xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_av_play_arrow"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/image"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical|right|end"
            app:rippleColor="@color/color_primary_light" />
```

So what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: goes away if I set my elevation to 0dp so I think I'll do that just for older phones

Comment: What is your parent layout? What is it width/height? Did you try removing some attributes from FAB? Did you try changing some to different values? Did you try moving it to another fragment?

Comment: The parent layout is `CoordinatorLayout`. Actually I have tried almost everything you mention because I wasn't using `CoordinatorLayout` before and had to learn how to use it so I tried a lot of things.

Comment: This is very strange. I have device with API 16 where FAB is in RelativeLayout and shadow is displaying properly. Are you using `com.android.support:design:22.2.0` with excluded `support-v4` module (which is imported separatly `compile('com.android.support:support-v4:+')` )?

Comment: I am using 22+ so it should be 22.2 if that is the latest. I have pretty much the exact same FAB (same attributes) on another app and it displays fine but it doesn't use the `CoordinatorLayout` however like I said I wasn't using it before and it had the same issue. I actually switched to it hoping it would fix that issue.

Comment: It goes away if I set the elevation to 0dp.

Comment: But when you do this, you loose shadow :/

Comment: This looks very much like a 9-patch issue. Is ic_av_play_arrow a nine-patch?

Comment: @kcoppock No it is not but your answer fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're making the `FloatingActionButton` an unexpected size. The `FloatingActionButton` in the support library only supports two sizes, and it must be set using the `fabSize` attribute.

You should change:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
```

to be:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

If you want a smaller version:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="mini"
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Comment: I have the same problem when I use wrap_content for the width and height. The lines in the shadow aren't as large as the image in the question, but they are still there.
This only happens on my 4.4.3 device. My lollipop and pre-4.4 devices work as expected.

Comment: @Daisy you might want to look at this bug report then https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179474&q=floatingactionbutton&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: As you hinted: Google currently only wants two sizes for Floating Action Buttons.  Try different sizes at your own risk!

Comment: It seems like app:fabCustomSize="48dp"  (or some other values) works good for custom FAB sizes. This feature might have been added later.