# Floating action button has a grey box with rounded corners in the dropshadow

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I plan on using floating action buttons to control audio like how Google Play Music does it.

When testing on Android 4.4.4 it has a square background with rounded corners behind it that when clicked change their radius. When testing on Android 7.0 it works fine.

[image: Fab]

Here's the XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_skip_previous_black_24dp"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link. [My FloatingActionButton has some weird lines coming out of it on 4.4 and lower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303727/my-floatingactionbutton-has-some-weird-lines-coming-out-of-it-on-4-4-and-lower)
There are only two sizes supported by the support library. So I think you have to change width and height.